# Get array through an jQuery AJAX call doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
 var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
$.ajax({
                    data: {order: data, actionFor: 'main_articles'},
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'updateDisplayOrder.php',
                    success: function (msg) { //re-number the rows from 1 to n
                       //code goes here
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("An error occurred");
                    });
```

And the PHP:

```
    require_once('../lib/common/db_connect.php');
    $ids = array();
    $actionFor = $_POST['actionFor'];
    foreach ($_POST['order'] as $value) //error here {
    //more code goes here
    }
```

The problem is that I get this error on the foreach line:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I noticed that if I change this line:

```
 data: {order: data, actionFor: 'main_articles'},
```

To

```
data:data
```

And in the PHP :

```
foreach ($_POST['order'] as $value) //error here {
```

To

```
foreach ($_POST['item'] as $value)
```

It Works great.
Why? How can I fox it? thanks!

Comment: Your POST parameter will be a string; if that string is actually JSON, you need to parse it to be an array before trying to iterate through it using `foreach`.

Comment: What do you get from `var_dump($_POST['order']);`?

Comment: @Styphon I got this: 'string(35) "item[]=2&item[]=1&item[]=3&item[]=4"'

Comment: @NaveTseva We'll there's your answer. It's not an array, it's a string. As Anthony Grist said, you need to parse it into an array first.

Comment: @Styphon Yes I noticed it now, can you take a look again at the question? I updated it and it seems strange to me that it's a string

Comment: `serialize` converts it to a string.

Comment: @Quentin Than why it worked befor?

Comment: @NaveTseva — Because you pass a string to `data` it will use that. If you pass an object, then it will serialise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST['order']` contains a string, not an array. You need to parse your string into an array first. Try this:

```
$order = array();
$stg1 = explode("&", $_POST['order']);
$i = 0;
foreach($stg1 as $keyval) {
    list($key, $val) = explode("=", $keyval);
    $order[$i++] = $val;
}
```

Then you can do your `foreach($order as $value)` as you wish.